# in matlab multiple count ifs in matrix

Tags: matlab

Say I have the following data, `S =`

```
Year    Week Postcode
2009    24  2035
2009    24  4114
2009    24  4127
2009    26  4114
2009    26  4556
2009    27  7054
2009    27  6061
2009    27  4114
2009    27  2092
2009    27  2315
2009    27  7054
2009    27  4217
2009    27  4551
2009    27  2035
2010    1   4132
2010    1   2155
2010    5   4114 ... (>60000 rows)
```

In Matlab, I would like to create a matrix with:

column 1: year (2006-2014)

column 2: week (1-52 for each year)

then the next `n` columns are unique postcodes where the data in each of these columns counts the occurrences from my data, `S`.

For example:

```
year  week  2035    4114    4127    4556    7054
2009    24   1        1       1       0       0
2009    25   0        0       0       0       0
2009    26   0        1       0       1       0
2009    27   1        1       0       0       2
2009    28   0        0       0       0       0
```

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: You should show what you have *tried*... See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks for your comment and usually I would have provided some code but in this case I have no clue where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script which achieves this tabulation. The output is in the `data` table. You should:

- Read the documentation on [unique](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), [tables](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/), [sortrows](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html). As these are the key tools I used below.
- Adapt the script to work with your data. This may involve changing matrices to cell arrays to deal with string inputs etc.
- Possibly adapt this to be a function, for cleaner use if this is used regularly / on different data.

Code, fully commented for explanation:

```
% Use rng for repeatability in rand, n = num data entries
rng('default')
n = 100;

% Set up test data. You would use 3 equal length vectors of real data here
years = floor(rand(n,1)*9 + 2006);        % random integer between 2006,2014
weeks = floor(rand(n,1)*52 + 1);          % random integer between 1, 52
postcodes = floor(rand(n,1)*10)*7 + 4000; % arbitrary integers over 4000

% Create year/week values like 2017.13, get unique indices
[~, idx, ~] = unique(years + weeks/100);

% Set up table with year/week data
data = table();
data.Year = years(idx);
data.Week = weeks(idx);
% Get columns
uniquepostcodes = unique(postcodes);
% Cycle over unique columns, assign data
for ii = 1:numel(uniquepostcodes)
    % Variable names cannot start with a numeric value, make start with 'p'
    postcode = ['p', num2str(uniquepostcodes(ii))];
    % Create data column variable for each unique postcode
    data.(postcode) = zeros(size(data.Year,1),1);
    % Count occurences of postcode in each date row
    % This uses logical indexing of original data, looking for all rows 
    % which satisfy year and week of current row, and postcode of column.
    for jj = 1:numel(data.Year)
        data.(postcode)(jj) = sum(years == data.Year(jj) & ...
                                  weeks == data.Week(jj) & ...
                                  postcodes == uniquepostcodes(ii));
    end
end

% Sort week/year data so all is chronological
data = sortrows(data, [1,2]);

% To check all original data was counted, you could run
% sum(sum(table2array(data(:,3:end))))
% ans = n, means that all data points were counted somewhere
```

On my PC, this takes less than 2.4 seconds for `n = 60,000`. There are almost definitely optimisations which can be made, but for something which may be used infrequently, this seems acceptable.

There is a linear increase in processing time, relative to the number of unique postcodes. This is because of the loop structure. So if you double the unique postcodes (20 rather than my example of 10) the time is nearer 4.8 seconds - twice as long.

If this solves your problem, consider accepting this as the answer.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!